# What did I do wrong in my dual drive partitioning?

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I've formatted Windows 10 from my dual drive notebook (128GB SSD + 1TB HDD) and installed Ubuntu., but I don't know exactly if I've only used my HDD while partitioning and left the SSD out. And also, why is some of it unallocated.
Should I format and partition again?
I find it quite hard to do it, and guarantee it will use both the SSD and the HDD.
This is how it looks like:

```
HDD
/dev/sda    931.51 GB
Partition   Locked  Filesys MountPt     Size    Used        Unused      Flags
/dev/sda1   Y   fat32   /boot/efi   487 MB      7.05 MB     479.95 MB   boot,esp
/dev/sda2   Y   ext4    /            38.15 GB   6.93 GB     31.22 GB    
/dev/sda3   Y   linux-swap           15.26 GB   0           15.26 GB
/dev/sda4       unallocated         877.83 GB

SSD
/dev/sdb    119.24 GB
/dev/sdb1   Y   ext4    /home       119.24 GB   3.08 GB     116.16 GB
```

My initial intention was to use the SSD for Ubuntu and the HDD for files. (I'm not sure what would be best too)

I've used [this tutorial](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/split-ubuntu-between-hdd-ssd/) to partition the drives.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: `sudo parted -l` provides a much more succinct and text only view of drives and partitions.and https://linuxhint.com/parted_linux/ is a good introduction to its use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote... "'I've formatted Windows 10 from my (dual drive) notebook" (hybrid being a term with a very different meaning) but what I see is you've removed Windows 10, made the HDD your boot and OS drive with a dedicated swap partition, and made the SSD /home.

If you reinstall Ubuntu, first erase both drives. Boot from your LiveUSB using gparted, unlock all drives showing a key icon in the second column, click the checkmark in the icon bar, and close gparted.

Run installation again, and install to the SSD only.  When you choose manual partitioning, it gives you the choice of which device to install to, which should be /dev/sdb .

With Ubuntu 18.04 and later, you do not need a dedicated swap partition unless you intend to use Hibernation (and that's easy to change later if you do find a need for Hibernation).

Once installation is complete, then reboot so you're running from the SSD without the LiveUSB attached. Then, use gparted again, and re-partition and reformat the HDD into one large ext4 partition.

You can then use the HDD for media storage in addition to what's in the SSD.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and for the hybrid correction.
I've done that...Root, efi and swap in my SDD, and separated /home ext4 in my HD.

I was just in doubt if I should allocate all the rest of my SDD space (discounting the swap I actually wanna keep) for root, or if I could have two homes.
By doing that, I avoided leaving all the space unallocated like the first time, but actually now I got an unnecessary big root of 100GB... which I can't use.

Besides that, it seems to be working well, except for the 'system program problem' messages I've been receiving. lol